# every ping get responded by local address

Tags: networking, ubuntu-20.04

I was trying to ping some websites from my laptop but every time i got response from my wifi router.
But When I Connect My Cellphone with the same router ping and other thing works fine.
By pinging Google (from my laptop) I got the following output:

```
PING google.com.ib-wrb304n.setup.in (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.2.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.10 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.2.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=8.29 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.2.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=11.9 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.2.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=8.54 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.2.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=8.56 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.2.1): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=7.82 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.2.1): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=8.52 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.2.1): icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=8.42 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.2.1): icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=8.45 ms
```

also all apt requests failing due to this.
but if i connect my laptop to my cellphone's wifi it works fine.
i've tried reinstalling my os also by downloading fresh iso files.
But Nothing Seems To Work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has no GW, so it arps for Google, the router replies with it's MAC via proxy ARP, and then to the pings.  Check your config, arp cache and ISP.

Comment: can i know the commands as i am new to ubuntu,and thanks for your reply
By The Way Here Is The Output of arp -a Command

`? (192.168.2.211) at 42:5c:5b:21:00:3e [ether] on wlp3s0
_gateway (192.168.2.1) at 00:1e:a6:d1:21:be [ether] on wlp3s0`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you clear the arp cache and then ping google, only the GW ARP entry should re-appear.  (first close your browser and all other connections, of course)  EXAMPLE:

```
Mac_3.2.57$sudo arp -d -a
10.0.0.14 (10.0.0.14) deleted
10.0.0.229 (10.0.0.229) deleted
10.0.0.255 (10.0.0.255) deleted
224.0.0.251 (224.0.0.251) deleted
239.255.255.250 (239.255.255.250) deleted
Mac_3.2.57$arp -a
Mac_3.2.57$ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.165.142): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.165.142: icmp_seq=0 ttl=57 time=20.942 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.165.142: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=21.516 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.165.142: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=20.725 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.165.142: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=19.750 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 19.750/20.733/21.516/0.637 ms
Mac_3.2.57$arp -a
? (10.0.0.1) at 5c:76:95:eb:28:43 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
Mac_3.2.57$
```

Comment: I've tried `sudo arp -d -a` after closing all my applications
the result of `arp -a` was empty.
But after reconnecting the result of `arp -a` was
`_gateway (192.168.2.1) at 00:1e:a6:d1:21:be [ether] on wlp3s0`
And
`ping google.com
PING google.com.ib-wrb304n.setup.in (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.2.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.12 ms
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
`
**i shorten the output because of comment limitation**
Also It's happening with only my wifi router with cell wifi it's working fine

Comment: After thinking more clearly, It looks more like DNS "proxy".  What OS is this?  Who is your ISP?  Please post "nslookup google.com" (or equivalent) output.  You probably should work with your ISP.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 20.04
Here Is The Output
`nslookup google.com`
`Server:  127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: google.com
Address: 142.250.194.14
Name: google.com
Address: 2404:6800:4002:81e::200e
`

Comment: I Think that `NetworkManager` Is Changing the dns to 127.0.0.53.
Now The Question Is How To Tell `NetworkManager` to always use google dns by default